# Deriving the normal form for Linear Second-Order PDE's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-transformations

I'm reading Fritz's PDE book. At page 37 we are discussing the equation $$au_{xx}+2bu_{xy}+cu_{yy}+2du_{x}+2eu_{y}+fu=0$$

where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ depend on $x,y$. The writer then introduces new variables $$\xi=\phi(x,y),\enspace \enspace \eta=\psi(x,y)$$

Then "transforms" the original linear equation into one of the same type $$Lu=A(\xi,\eta)u_{\xi\xi}+2B(\xi,\eta)u_{\xi \eta}+\cdots=0$$

where $A=a\phi_x^2+2b\phi_x\phi_y+c\phi_y^2$, $B=a\phi_x\psi_x+b(\phi_x\psi_y+\phi_y\psi_x)+c\phi_y\psi_y$, and $C=a\psi_x^2+2b\psi_x\psi_y+c\psi_y^2$ etc

What exactly is this transformation process? This part of the book discusses hyperbolic/elliptic/parabolic PDE's and their normal forms.

Comment: It is just making coordinate transformations to put the various second order PDEs into their canonical form. Sometimes this makes the equations easier to solve.

Comment: This is basically the same (on an abstract level) as this question from yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291952/how-do-i-use-a-transformation-on-a-second-order-differential-equation#comment8938437_4291952. By the way, “John's PDE book” would be the standard expression (Fritz is the first name and John is the surname).